# Sonar is stopped or not running

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sonarqube, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to install sonarqube and integrate with GCP-SQL’s Postgres server

I tried to give the GCP postgres DB’s superuser privileges and also tried with newer versions of sonar/ postgres. But same result i end up at below error. Can u pls help with postgres DB settings and what might i have missed.

Directly in the DB i am able to query with sonar user.

```
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:prefer-type-guard
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:number-literal-format
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:prefer-const
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:cyclomatic-complexity
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:no-void-expression
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:comment-format
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule external_tslint:no-duplicated-branches
2020.08.28 03:16:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S3340
2020.08.28 03:16:11 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
### The error may exist in org.sonar.db.rule.RuleMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.rule.RuleMapper.selectIndexingRulesByUuids-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select       r.uuid as "uuid",       r.plugin_name as "repository",       r.plugin_rule_key as "pluginRuleKey",       r.name as "name",       r.description as "description",       r.description_format as "descriptionFormat",       r.priority as "severity",       r.status as "status",       r.is_template as "isTemplate",       r.is_external as "isExternal",       r.system_tags as "systemTags",       r.security_standards as "securityStandards",       t.plugin_rule_key as "templateRuleKey",       t.plugin_name as "templateRepository",       r.plugin_config_key as "internalKey",       r.language as "language",       r.rule_type as "type",       r.created_at as "createdAt",       r.updated_at as "updatedAt"     from rules r     left outer join rules t on t.uuid = r.template_uuid         where                   r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?         or           r.uuid=?              order by r.created_at asc
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:144)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.selectIndexingRulesByUuids(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.db.rule.RuleDao.lambda$scrollIndexingRulesByKeys$7(RuleDao.java:213)
    at org.sonar.db.DatabaseUtils.executeLargeInputsWithoutOutput(DatabaseUtils.java:214)
    at org.sonar.db.rule.RuleDao.scrollIndexingRulesByKeys(RuleDao.java:211)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.index.RuleIndexer.doIndexRules(RuleIndexer.java:154)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.index.RuleIndexer.index(RuleIndexer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.index.RuleIndexer.postCommit(RuleIndexer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.index.RuleIndexer.commitAndIndex(RuleIndexer.java:110)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.start(RegisterRules.java:145)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.start(StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:48)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:85)
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:82)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.executeStartupTasks(PlatformImpl.java:198)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.access$400(PlatformImpl.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$1.lambda$doRun$1(PlatformImpl.java:122)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(PlatformImpl.java:370)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$1.doRun(PlatformImpl.java:122)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.run(PlatformImpl.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:339)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1155)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2043)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
2020.08.28 03:16:12 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
2020.08.28 03:16:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud SQL not allow creating or have access to users with superuser attributes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions). If you need full self-managed PostgreSQL.You can create GCE instance and [deploy the DB service](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) there.